Matrix decomposition in Julia
i have a big grid with a matrix(3x3) associated at each point. I want a perform a symmetric and skew-symmetric decomposition. I know that the algorithm is
=0.5(+T)+0.5(−T)
I was checking the linear algebra library in Julia but i cant find this decomposition( i found Qr,LU,SDV,...)
It is available in Julia ( or from an external source) or i have to write it?
Thank you in advance
I want a decomposition in symmetric and anti symmetric part of a matrix. i checked the LinearAlgebra Library from Julia

How big is big?

6 million points

does this decomp have a name?

I only found that decomposition like "symmetric and skew-symmetric decomposition"

might wanna take a detour through the math stackexchange so they can help identify/name the math and numerical approach to solving it.

A straightforward decomposition can be done like this
using StaticArrays
A = randn(SMatrix{3,3,Float64}, 4, 5)  # create initial data
Symm = 0.5 .* (A .+ adjoint.(A))
SkewSymm = A .- Symm  # or   0.5 .* (A .- adjoint.(A))

I'm using StaticArrays for the 3x3 inner matrices, since this is much more efficient than using regular Matrix.

If you are using Julia 1.10 or above, LinearAlgebra.jl provides the LinearAlgebra.hermitianpart method. You could always have a look at how it's implemented and implement the skew-symmetric part yourself.
That option allocates the factorization matrices, which might be costly. An alternative is to use LinearOperators.jl, which provides lazy (i.e non-allocative) operators that behave like marices. You could use that to define your sym/skew parts without actually computing the matrix, just it's action on vectors.
